# Cordova: at what step in development should I add platforms?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web, build

I am developing a mobile app using Apache Cordova

I have created a new project with `cordova example com.domain.example ExampleApp`

The CLI then creates the basic skeleton with the starter files

I then add platforms with `cordova platform add ios` and so on

I notice that if I browse the platform directory, each added platform has a `www` directory that contains a copy of the files in the project's main `www` directory, as well as some settings from the main `config.xml` file in a similar file in the platform directory.

I'm not anywhere near the stage of building yet, but am wondering, after editing the contents of the main `www` directory and adding new settings to the main `config.xml` file, will all of my changes get applied to the corresponding directory and file in the platform directories upon build?

So I'm asking, is it a) ok to add platforms to my project before I start developing in the `www` directory and so on, and the other files will be updated when the app is built, or b) do I need to wait until I'm ready to build and add the platforms just before building so all the content in the `www` directory is correctly copied to each platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `cordova prepare` it will copy the changes from www and config.xml to the platforms (you can also do it per platform with `cordova prepare platformName`)
Other commands like `cordova run` and `cordova build` will also run prepare internally.

So, add the platforms whenever you want, but you should test the app on a real device sooner or later and you will have to add the platforms for that

Comment: thank! that's exactly what I needed. nice and simple. I copied my project for testing, changed a few things in the config.xml and www directory, ran the command and it updated all of the corresponding files in all of the platforms. Thanks again :)